# real-time data update with cloud firestore via api rest call

Tags: rest, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I would like to create a Cloud Firestore API while maintaining my business rule within Cloud Functions, I would like to process these requirements in my Angular application and update the data in real time.

Is it possible to do real time updates if I create a Rest API with Cloud Firestore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're building your REST API on top of Cloud Functions, this will not be possible.  Cloud Functions doesn't support [HTTP chunked transfer encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding), nor does it support HTTP/2 streaming that would be required to let the client keep a socket open for the duration of the listen.  Instead, functions are required to send their *entire* response to the client at once, with a size less than 10MB, within the timeout of the function (max 9 minutes).

Comment: Sure, I'm using angularfire2 ... but what doesn't make me very happy is that the system business rule is all on the front end.

The only way to update data on the screen in real time is to use angularfire2 to work with Cloud Firestore?

Comment: That's the easiest way.  If you want to use another backend that supports HTTP chunked transfer encoding or HTTP/2 streaming, you could try that instead.  It will be a lot of coding.